# Sorting based on different properties with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ES, I have two different kind of index that represent different models.
For example, in the first index, I have `_body:{created_at : Date}` and in the second index I have `_body:{date : Date}`.

Is it possible query the server in order to have sorted results from both indexes related to different properties (in the example `created_at` and `date`)? To be more clear, the order should be based on the combination of the two fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with function score

```
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {},
        "functions": [
            {
                 "field_value_factor": {
                     "field": "created_at",
                     "factor": 2,
                     "missing": 1
                 }
             },
            {
                 "field_value_factor": {
                     "field": "date",
                     "factor": 2,
                     "missing": 1
                 }
             },
        ],
        "score_mode": "sum",
        "boost_mode": "sum"
    }

}
```